# Container Orchestrator Support Missing in VS 2022 ASP.NET Core 6 Web Api

Tags: containers

I am using virtualized Windows 10 in VMware Workstation.

I have also turn on the features Windows Subsystem For Linux, Windows Hypervisor Platform and Virtual Machine Platform.

I have also in VMWare setting enable the Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT etc...

Then I install the Docker Destop and also installed the WSL 2 and when I start the Docker Desktop with no error on WSL issues

I then created a new ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition version Version 17.7.1 with Docker Enabled and with the WeatherForecast controller in it and no other contollers.

When I right click the project, I couldn't find Container Orchestrator Support.

Did I miss anything here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that option was removed since VS 2019, you can have a look at this link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-container-orchestrator-support-missing-in-vs20/586334

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your project is in a folder under the solution. If the project file is at or above the solution file you can't add compose support. You get that choice when you create an new project. (Place solution and project in the same directory)